# jquery Setting option selected with known value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have the next select:

```
<select name="priority" id="priority" class="update_priority">
    <option value="root" label="Without parent">Without parent</option>
    <option value="72" label="Rank3">Rank3</option>
    <option value="71" label="Rank1">Rank1</option>
    <option value="67" label="Rank2">Rank2</option>
    <option value="64" label="Rank4">Rank4</option>
</select>
```

In JS i have a variable with something value. For example:

```
selected = 71;
```

Now, with help of jQuery I want to make option selected with this value(in our example 71).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you don't need jquery for this. you can just use plain old javascript:

```
document.getElementById("priority").value = "71";
```

But if you still want to with jquery you can do the same thing:

```
$("#priority").val("71")
```

EDIT: Here is an example. You can comment out either one you want to see the other one work:
http://jsfiddle.net/BupWA/